# is $ f_n(x) = (1+x^n)^{1/n}$ uniformly convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

does the following series of function is uniformly convergent in $[0,\infty]$?

$ f_n(x) = (1+x^n)^{1/n}$

I found that $f_n \to f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & 1 \le x \\
1, & 0 \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$

Comment: It is. It may be helpful to show uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ and on $[1,+\infty)$ separately.

Comment: No, not series but sequence of functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

For $ x \in [0,1)$, as $n \to \infty$, we have 
$$
\left|(1+x^n)^{1/n}-1\right|=\left|\frac1nx^n+O(x^{2n})\right|=O(x^n).
$$ For $ x \in (1,\infty)$, as $n \to \infty$, we have 
$$
\left|(1+x^n)^{1/n}-x\right|=\left|\frac1n\frac1{x^{n-1}}+O\left(\frac1{x^{2n-1}}\right)\right|=O\left(\frac1{x^{n}}\right).
$$ For the case $x=1$, observe that
$$
2^{1/n}=1+O\left(\frac1n\right).
$$